# Обработка 404 на Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

```
express = require('express');
var app = express();
//Установливаем шаблонизатор handlbars

var handlbars = require('express-handlebars').create({'defaultLayout':'main'});
app.engine('handlebars', handlbars.engine);
app.set('view.engine', 'handlebars');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

//Главная
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('houme');
});

//О нас
app.get('/about', function(req, res){
    res.render('about');
});

app.use(function(req, res){
    res.status(404);
    res.render('404');
});   

app.use(function(err, res, req, next){
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500);
    res.render('500');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express запущен на порту '+ app.get('port') + '...');
});
```

Ошибка пр заходе на любую страницу роута.

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: `app.use(function(err, res, req, next)` Вы тут местами req и res перепутали

Comment: Вылезла другая фигня

Error: Failed to lookup view "500" in views directory "E:\Node Projects\views"
    at EventEmitter.render (E:\Node

Comment: у вас res.render('500'); должен рендерить файл, которого нет. Замените на res.send('500'); чтобы просто текст 500 вылез

Comment: Спасибо разобрался.